# Store different item types in dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I want to store a dictionary as:

`[String : AnyItem]`

because the format will be

`["codename" : "title", "image" : UIImage("imageName")]`

but I am having a difficult type accomplishing this. The ultimate goal is to have an array full of these types of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a dictionary value that can hold anything, you need `Any` (rather than `AnyType`.

But this will be a real pain – whenever you want to get the value out, you’ll have to covert the types back every time, and if you mess up doing that, you’ll get all sorts of errors.

Instead, consider using a tuple – a pair of the two types you want.  You can name the elements to make them easier to access:

```
var images: [(codename: String, image: UIImage)] = []

if let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/24d29e1ff91b68642bbef96b43b5e119?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"),
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url),
    let image = UIImage(data: data) {

        images.append(codename: "AlexAvatar", image: image)
}

images[0].codename  // name of the first image in the array
images[0].image     // the first image in the array
```

Alternatively, if you are going to want to address the images by name, why not use the “codename” field as the dictionary key?

```
var images: [String:UIImage)] = []

if let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/24d29e1ff91b68642bbef96b43b5e119?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"),
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url),
    let image = UIImage(data: data) {

        images["AlexAvatar"] = image
}

for (codename, image) in images {
    // iterate over the codename/image pairs
}
```

If your actual data requirements are more complicated, consider a struct instead of a tuple.